# PHP one time execution(Payroll system)

Tags: php, system

Is there any way to restrict in PHP to generate a payroll of an employee only once?

Comment: create record in a db and when you executed it (Payroll system) mark field in table true. and if script attempts to execute it check db if record is true don't otherwise execute it.

Comment: I'm just getting the idea, I have lots of code here, no time and space to post it all. Somehow, people answered and understood my question. Thanks to THOSE who are helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess this is what you are looking for. It's pretty simple answer to your question.

Create a record in a db/table and when you executed it (Payroll system) mark the field in table as true. If script attempts to execute code for payroll check the db if record is true  otherwise execute that item.

Comment: Thanks, I was just getting the idea. Very helpful.